# Moving coupon box in cart page into before cart_totals div

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, coupon

There are a lot of places where one can learn how to move coupon box within the checkout page on Woocommerce, but I can't find any article or question to do the same in the **cart page**. Is it possible to move the coupon box in cart page into before cart_totals div via functions.php?

I have been trying by copying and pasting the code on cart.php but something in the theme makes it not work. I presume that doing it in the functions.php would solve the issue in a very neat way.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please put  code here so any one can get it exactly issue.

Comment: I don't understand what code you are talking about? My question is, quote "Is it possible to move the coupon box in cart page into before cart_totals div via functions.php?" and quote "I presume that doing it in the functions.php would solve the issue in a very neat way. How can I do it?"

Comment: Yes it should be possible… If you search a little, you will see that you can [customize woocommerce templates via your active child theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) … The template to be customized is `cart/cart.php` … Good coding